# Google firebase database with google functions running locally

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have an app connected to google firebase realtime database. I want to test google cloud functions as a server for running backend functions triggered once every day or triggered by data changed in the database.

I have an emulator instance running locally with a typescript function that I wrote.
I have the realtime database running, connected to the app and working well.

Now when I change data in the database, the functions are not being triggered.

function in index.ts:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";


exports.simpleDbFunction = functions.region('europe-west1').database.ref('/some path in the database')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        console.log("functions triggered by datachange:", snap.val())
    });
```

the firebase project is connected to the correct project (using the interface in the terminal).
the app and realtime database are currently working and I can see changes in the data inside the firebase console.

What am I missing?

I've also tried the more complicated example from google's documents (makeUppercase function). But when it didn't work I went back to a simple function that is triggered on data creation and prints to the console.

Edit: I notice that in the emulator UI the real time database is empty. Shouldn't it connect to the real time database of the app? isn't that why I connected the emulator to a specific project?
Edit2: I tried changing the function line to:

> functions.region('europe-west1').database.instance("the URL of the
> rtdb").ref(...

and I get an error saying that the event function has malformed resource member

Comment: Sounds like your problem might be that the Emulator Suite creates a new, local temporary RTDB instance - it is not your actual project database.

Comment: We can't see that the code that gets written to the database matches what the function is set to trigger on.  Please edit the question to show all of the relevant code and steps to take with enough information that someone could copy it and fully reproduce the behavior you describe. Consider also reading about how to create a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that's focused on reproducing the problem.

Comment: @evces I think you're right (notice what I editied into the end of the question). How can I connect to the real time database?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the comment, I do though think that the function that I have shown from the index.ts should be triggered from any change in the RTDB, so I'm not sure which code you're referring to? Can you clarify?

Comment: There are two main pieces of code here.  The code that writes to the database and the function that you want to get trigger as a result of that write.  It's not sufficient to show "/some path in the database" - we need to see that everything is working together as you expect using the actual code.  Again please read the link I provided about providing a good example that anyone can use to repro the problem.

Comment: @DougStevensongh I expect the onWrite() to be triggered when I'm changing/deleting/adding data manually through the console.

Answer (score 0):

So I kinda solved it:

1. I found out that you can't really connect from a local emulator to the production environment of your actual google firebase. (Which is kinda weird, you have to commit to this technology even before you had a chance to see any code in action) <-- **fix me if I'm wrong about this**
2. If you use realtime database cloud functions you can't use any region other than 'us-central1'. as mentioned in this document:
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations
3. You can connect your app to the local emulator on your machine!
   Get your database instance:

> FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

Add the following line in your app (which is weird) before the first database operation:

> database.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9004);

change 9004 to your local realtime database port.